# Intellij open a project file as non-project file on debugging

Tags: php, debugging, intellij-idea

If I start debugging on my IntelliJ, the IDE open the file which I want to debug in a new tab as a non-project file, and I don't know how I can solve this.

I switched the OS from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 and reinstalled IntelliJ but the .idea folder in the project is the same, so all marked folders should be the same as well. On Ubuntu 18.04 everything worked with debugging.

Can anyone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Here is a image:

[image: https://ibb.co/BP6LwFQ]

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue. I've a sym-link from the HDD where the project is located to my home folder and open the project from the home folder, so may the ide or debugger gets the real path and think that the file isn't a project file >.<

Answer (score 1):

Report it on the issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125379

As a workaround try to use this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7635-non-project-files-unlocker

Comment: I think it isnt a bug, cause the same IntelliJ version on Ubuntu 18.04 works fine. And I don't want disable the Dialog, I want that the debugger don't open the file, thats in the project, as a non project file. I think there is some configuration issue. That the debugger don't know the source folder or something, but I don't know how I configure my project correctly, I didn't change anything after the switch.

Comment: So the IDE behaves differently on two OS versions? Sounds like a bug.